# Set content to TinyMCE on document.ready

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tinymce

How can I set the text to TinyMCE on `document.ready()`? I tried in the following way but it doesn't work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        init_instance_callback: function (editor) {
            alert('test');
            editor.activeEditor.setContent('custom');
        }
    });
});
```

I have done the following way which is working fine when I have my content as follows in my database `<p>New topic started, lets have some posts</p>`

```
 $('#TopicDescription').html('@(TempData["TopicDescription"] != null ? @Html.Raw(TempData["TopicDescription"].ToString()).ToString() : "")');
```

But when I have the content as `<p>Long reply</p><p>Long reply</p>` this is the error I am getting in console[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (**Tinymce 4**):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup : function(ed)
        {
            ed.on('init', function(evt)
            {
                alert('test');
                ed.setContent('<p>custom</p>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Try (**Tinymce 3**):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     tinymce.init({
        selector: 'textarea',
        setup : function(ed)
        {
            ed.oninit.add(function(evt)
            {
                alert('test');
                ed.setContent('<p>custom</p>');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `Thariama` No it doesn't

Comment: are you using tinymce 4 or tinymce 3?

Comment: that is important to know -  i will update my answer

Comment: Hi as shown in the question when I am having large text with line breaks and images I am unable to show it can you help me on that

Comment: @Dotnet: do you still have a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea',
            plugins: "code image"
        });
```